# How to detect if Recyclerview is empty in advance?

Tags: android

I am making an app base on sqllitedabase .First i insert the records to database and then retrieve
in another activity on recyclerview. But when thier is no records inserted i want to show that the recyclerview is empty.

i try this but failed

```
case R.id.show_records:
    if (MainActivity.adapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no record found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent (this, MainActivity.class)); 
    }
```

Comment: Can you directly check the number of records in your database instead of checking your adapter item count ?

Comment: Add that code from where you set data to `RV`

Comment: MainActivity.adapter is a static field? If so, that's a poor idea

Comment: If you are using a list or array list then try list.isEmpty();

Answer (score 1):

```
 String count= String.valueOf(sqLiteDatabase1.rawQuery("SELECT employee_id FROM 
 employees", null).getCount());
 Toast.makeText(this, ""+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 if(count!=null)
 { startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));}
 else {
 Toast.makeText(this, "no record found", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you assigned the adapter again without adding it to the recycleviw.
A better way is to check if the records are empty from database.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
 if(is no records || adapter.get your list data is empty) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"no record found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           }else{  
         startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)); 
 }
```